# Cannot receive incoming JSON from Telegram webHook ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, telegram

So the problem is that I have set a webHook address for my Telegram bot like this: 
`https://api.telegram.org/bot<TOKEN>/setWebHook?url=https://evolhookah.com/Home/ReceiveWebhook`

Afterwards, I received confirmation in JSON format stating that from now Telegram will send messages to that URL.

Then I created a method ReceiveWebhook(), which is responsible for handling incoming requests, which used to look like these methods (none of them worked):

```
    public ActionResult ReceiveJSON(int? id)
    {
        Stream req = Request.InputStream;
        req.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
        string receivedJson = new StreamReader(req).ReadToEnd();
        var bs = new TgDesserialize(); //Class containing JSON desserializing function
        PeopleAttributes people = bs.desserializer(receivedJson); //desserializer manages with desserializing received JSON and returns an object people filled up with necessary values
        return Content(people.firstName);
    }
```

Unfortunately idea with a stream did NOT work, then I decided to receive incoming JSON as a string, and this is how it looked like:

```
    public ActionResult JSONString(String receivedJSON)
    {
        var bs = new TgDesserialize(); 
        PeopleAttributes people = bs.desserializer(receivedJSON); 
        return Content(people.firstName);
    }
```

Problem: Everytime I receive a webhook, I either get null JSON or cannot receive it properly in the controller.

Questions:

1. Is there any possible way I can check that Telegram is sending JSON with data inside while sending a webHook?
2. Why do I always get NULLs, while `https://api.telegram.org/bot<TOKEN>/getUpdates` shows that I have data inside JSON?
3. Am I receiving my JSON in a wrong way in a controller? If yes, what is the best practice of handling incoming JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a class based on the JSON from telegram.

Example:

Telegram JSON:

```
{ 
    "update_id": 1
    "message": { ... fill in message json here},
    .... other properties here
}
```

You then create a class:

```
public class TelegramUpdate
{
    public int update_id {get; set;}
    public Message message {get; set;}
    // other properties here
}

public class Message
{
    // message properties here
}
// ... More nested classes go here
```

Pro tip: If you have an example JSON-file, you can copy it, got Visual Studio=>Edit=> Paste Special=> Paste JSON as class. This will generate the classes for you

You can then add this class as a parameter to your webhook:

```
public ActionResult JSONString(TelegramUpdate update)
{
    return Content(update.message.from.first_name);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I suggest you to using [telegram.bot](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Telegram.Bot/) library and looking this example for [Webhook](https://github.com/MrRoundRobin/telegram.bot.examples/tree/master/Telegram.Bot.Examples.WebHook).
But in general:

1. install the [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) and post a manual message like the telegram webhook message to your controller. Then make sure there are no bugs in your controller.

A Postman sample:

```
{
    "update_id":10000,
    "message":{
      "date":1441645532,
      "chat":{
         "last_name":"Test Lastname",
         "id":1111111,
         "first_name":"Test",
         "username":"Test"
      },
      "message_id":1365,
      "from":{
         "last_name":"Test Lastname",
         "id":1111111,
         "first_name":"Test",
         "username":"Test"
      },
      "text":"/start"
    }
```

[image: Postman]

2. if your controller is true you must make sure that the Webhook message is sent by Telegram. You can download [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) and create a https proxy to your localhost.

Use this command in ngrok:

```
ngrok http 20201
```

20201 is your localhost port (localhost:20201).
Now ngrok give you a https link, and you must set that link as your telegram webhook (just like the way you said).
At this moment if telegram sends a webhook message for your bot then you can debug it in the localhost.

3. Finally, if you do not find the problem you must read the [Marvin's Patent Pending Guide to All Things Webhook](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webhooks) to check all the requirements again.

> 1. Supports IPv4, IPv6 is currently not supported for Webhooks.
> 2. Accepts incoming POSTs from 149.154.167.197-233 on port 443,80,88 or 8443.
> 3. Is able to handle TLS1.0+ HTTPS-traffic.
> 4. Provides a supported,non-wildcard, verified or self-signed certificate.
> 5. Uses a CN or SAN.that matches the domain you’ve supplied on setup.
> 6. Supplies all intermediate certificates to complete a verification chain.

Comment: can you suggest any option for my controller to handle the incoming JSON?

Comment: Just use telegram.bot library and it's handle the incoming messages. Have you seen the webhook example?

Answer (score 2):

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        try
        {

            var req = Request.InputStream; //get Request from telegram 
            var responsString = new StreamReader(req).ReadToEnd(); //read request
            RootObject ro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responsString);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Content("Error");
        }


        // This code hint to telegram Ttat , I Get Message And dont need to send this message again
        return Content("{\"ok\":true}");

    }
```

You then create a class:

```
 public class From
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public bool is_bot { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string language_code { get; set; }
}

public class Chat
{
    public long id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
}

public class ForwardFromChat
{
    public long id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Document
{
    public string file_name { get; set; }
    public string mime_type { get; set; }
    public string file_id { get; set; }
    public int file_size { get; set; }
}
public class Audio
{
    public int duration { get; set; }
    public string mime_type { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string performer { get; set; }
    public string file_id { get; set; }
    public int file_size { get; set; }
}
public class Photo
{
    public string file_id { get; set; }
    public int file_size { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
}
public class Video
{
    public int duration { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
    public string mime_type { get; set; }
    public Thumb thumb { get; set; }
    public string file_id { get; set; }
    public int file_size { get; set; }
}
public class Thumb
{
    public string file_id { get; set; }
    public int file_size { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
}
public class Message
{
    public int message_id { get; set; }
    public From from { get; set; }
    public Chat chat { get; set; }
    public int date { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
}

public class CaptionEntity
{
    public int offset { get; set; }
    public int length { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class EditedChannelPost
{
    public int message_id { get; set; }
    public Chat chat { get; set; }
    public int date { get; set; }
    public int edit_date { get; set; }
    public string caption { get; set; }
    public List<CaptionEntity> caption_entities { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public Document document { get; set; }
    public Video video { get; set; }
    public Audio audio { get; set; }
    public List<Photo> photo { get; set; }
}
public class ChannelPost
{
    public int message_id { get; set; }
    public Chat chat { get; set; }
    public int date { get; set; }
    public ForwardFromChat forward_from_chat { get; set; }
    public int forward_from_message_id { get; set; }
    public string forward_signature { get; set; }
    public int forward_date { get; set; }
    public string caption { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public List<CaptionEntity> caption_entities { get; set; }
    public Document document { get; set; }
    public Video video { get; set; }
    public Audio audio { get; set; }
    public List<Photo> photo { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public long update_id { get; set; }
    public ChannelPost channel_post { get; set; }
    public EditedChannelPost edited_channel_post { get; set; }
    public Message message { get; set; }
}
```

Enjoy it!