# Webhook in Telegram Bot can't receive any updates

Tags: ssl-certificate, webhooks, telegram, telegram-bot

I have problem when creating Telegram Bot with a webhook.

Currently I have done this:

- I have a cloud, with IP Address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, without a domain
  name
- I created certificate within JKS file inside a Java application (I have followed instructions from https://core.telegram.org/bots/self-signed)
- My certificate is self-signed, and I use IP Address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx as my CN
- I exported it to Public Key certificate to use later in 'setWebhook' command parameter
- I execute this command : curl -F "url=https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" -F "certificate=@my-pem-file.pem" https://api.telegram.org/botXXX:XXX/setWebhook
- I run my bot engine
- I try to call the URL in browser, with address : https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (GET method), and it works fine after browser 'add exception' to my self-signed certificate
  'works fine' means browser can recognize the public certificate, and it can display correct response as I developed
- I try to follow test script from https://core.telegram.org/bots/webhooks#testing-your-bot-with-updates, example is:

  **curl --tlsv1 -v -k -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache"  -d '{"update_id":10000,"message":{  "date":1441645532,"chat":{"last_name":"Test Lastname","id":1111111,"first_name":"Test","username":"Test"},"message_id":1365,"from":{"last_name":"Test Lastname","id":1111111,"first_name":"Test","username":"Test"},"text":"/start"}}' "https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"**

  It works fine.
- I am sure that parameter 'url' and 'certificate' in API of 'setWebhook' works fine, because when I call API of 'getWebhookInfo' to Telegram, it replied:

  **{
    "ok": true,
    "result": {
      "url": "https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
      "has_custom_certificate": true,
      "pending_update_count": 25,
      "last_error_date": 1484557151,
      "last_error_message": "Connection timed out",
      "max_connections": 40
    }
  }**
- I try to send any message to my bot, but nothing shown in my internal application log, and when I call API of 'getWebhookInfo' it always show the same, it said "**Connection timed out**"

What should I do in my certificate?

Comment: i am using https://www.cloudflare.com/ instead of custom certificate , but telegram only accept valid certificates , i mean when you add exception in your browser to proceed the page , is the main problem

Comment: Compiling the Webhook is complicated. I suggest you read the below post (Maybe it helps you): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39420903/cannot-receive-incoming-json-from-telegram-webhook-asp-net/39602790#39602790

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem at last week, webhooks worked and stopped (timeout error). It turned out because of the blocking of the telegram in Russia. My server was not in Russia, it was in Holland, but after the server was changed it all worked.